# Do you see the need for "buzzwords-in-question-titles" edits?

Tags: discussion, editing, title

*I see a pretty similar discussion (no, not that similar) [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377/how-should-we-fix-the-problem-of-bad-question-titles-on-ell).*

It's an **ancient** tradition in chemistry.SE to edit the buzzwords in question titles. (Don't think so? Take a look at these: [1](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/524/4945),  [2](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/4945), [3](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/566/4945), and [4](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/583/buzzwords-in-question-titles-season-4-experiments))

I see that usually the inexperienced users come up with something like these for question titles:

> I have a tense problem
>   This sentence is confusing me
>   What is the meaning of *this phrase*?

The titles, you've gotta admit, are a bit nonspecific. We do edit them in first observations in chemistry, so why not do something alike in here?

To have some fun, search for "problem", "question", "structure" and such. And hey, I'm not saying all the question titles with these searches are problematic.

Comment: Improved titles make for an improved site. Feel free to make improvements.

Comment: *Keywords*, absolutely yes. *Buzzwords*, absolutely not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We definitely have a lot of vague question titles! I don't know about buzzwords specifically, but in general I would definitely advocate for any title edit that better summarized the question's content. If that's your goal, go right ahead!

Comment: Well, not today. For two reasons: I'm going to bed, and editing a lot of questions at once will make the active page look a bit messy as old questions jump up to the top.

Comment: @MARamezani I don't think jumping older questions up to the top of the actives is such a bad thing. Sometimes a review of an older question can be a good thing!