# When should we hold The Retagging Event?

Tags: discussion, tags, chat, retagging

We're going to hold a chat event (Similar to [TCE](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/title-cleanup-event-tce-an-invitation)) to retag almost all of the [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) questions. Are you going to help? What day of the week and at what time are you willing to help us?

Personally I'd go with Friday, since it's the weekend here and the last weekday there (Friday evenings are famous for . . . well . . . ). We held a [TRE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/the-great-retagging-event-episode-1-the-one-taggers) at chem.SE and it was/is a success.

What do you think?

Comment: Friday's good. I'm usually free on Fridays,

Answer (score 1):

I will be happy assisting in this good work. However, we need to define first (and for that, we have an option of chat I think) which questions we shall consider to leave with 'grammar' tag. At times it may happen that the volunteers may find it confusing whether the question is actually of 'grammar' or not. In that case, we shall chat, take others' opinion and carry on.

Cleaning up the tag 'grammar' is very important as you suggested earlier. And, as I replied then, I'm ready now as well.

I'm available on weekends (not all those two days though) but the time won't be fixed. However, 'hours' will be fixed. Say, I contribute 3-4 hours of mine. Are you or anyone available all time?

Okay, in case if no one is there to chat, I leave those questions but surely mention them in chat.

I'll edit the questions that are typically of 'word usage/meaning'. I'll keep all tense and sentence related questions as grammar. Also, there are plenty of tags and as we check, we'll take decision on the spot.

Thank you for initiating this. All the best to **us**!

:)

Comment: Maulik that's how it's going to work: We're gonna start retagging, and any questions that can't be easily tagged can be discussed during the event. (See [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/2952/7448), and especially the linked chat logs) We're looking for the most convenient time for everyone. Hope this'd be as successful and fun as I plan it to be. :)

Comment: Now I really need you to tell me when, if any, are you going to participate. I have upvoted, but this isn't the answer I was looking for.